# Reusing dynamic TableViewCells without having to maintain of each cell's state in Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableView that uses a cell that has 3 expandable and collapsable subviews in them. I would prefer to maintain the state of these views in my UITableViewCell class itself (states as in `collapsed` or `expanded`)

Since they are reusable cells, currently, if I expand view 1 in cell A, and then scroll down to cell B, it's view 1 will be expanded. I don't want this. I want it collapsed. But, if I scroll back up to cell A, I want it to still be expanded.

Other than storing all of these states in an array or dictionary

```
var expandedViewOneCells: [Int] = []
var expandedViewTwoCells: [Int] = []
etc.
```

I would prefer to have the cells essentially of act individually and maintain their own state... But how would I do this when cells are reused? Keep in mind, I will always only have at most 3 of these kinds of cells, so can I set something like `only reuse after 3 cells`.

Would it be wise to keep an array of the cells I load, and then on `cellForRowAt` load the cell from that array based on the index and return it?

Comment: what is your source array?

Comment: You can keep an static array of cells of there aren't may of them -- say a few dozens. If there may be more cells, it would be better to keep the state separately.

Comment: @RobertDresler I have an array of what we call a `Match` but the match object has nothing to do with expanded states. It simply holds the data in each cell.

Comment: @Yonat Okay, so I will only have three of them at most. Therefore, you're saying I could create three instances of the cell as the view loads, and then store them in an array, and then just load them based on index in `cellForRowAt`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Reusing cells is useful for long tables, not an absolute requirement.

Comment: I think if you're recycling cells it would be wiser to store the state separately from the cell itself since you will run into the problem of managing that state when the cells get recycled and find yourself needing some state exterior to the cell to resolve that anyway.  If you do the array of cells solution that Yonat suggests you should store an array not just of the three types but rather containing an instance of each of the cells that will go into the table.  Otherwise you could have the same cell showing up twice at the same time and that won't be fun.

Answer (score 0):

In your `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` function try not to deque a cell but create a new instance of your cell

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = MyCustomCell()

    return cell
}
```

If you are loading your cell from a xib file you need a way to create your custom cell from that nib. Add the following method to your `CustomCell` class

```
static func loadFromNib() -> RequestTableViewCell {
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "\(MyCustomCell.self)", bundle: Bundle.main)
    let cell = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! MyCustomCell
    return cell
}
```

Then in your `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` this will create a new cell for every row and not reuse a cell when scrolling

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = MyCustomCell.loadFromNib()

    return cell
}
```

A solution like this may not be optimal if your table view has a lot of rows but for a **SMALL** amount of rows this should be okay

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 solutions to your problem:

1. Use 3 View Controllers. They should never get destroyed, and add / remove the corresponding VC's view on top of the `.contentView` of the cell as it appears or goes off-screen. See the solution here http://khanlou.com/2015/04/view-controllers-in-cells/ The Custom Cell itself is just a view, shouldn't really be concerned with the state, but if we move that logic to a View Controller - we should be fine, an we are not violating MVC. Plus, the View Controller can keep track of the height of the view, based on the state, and heightForRow(at:) can ask it for that
2. I'd use a Stack View as this is a perfect scenario for it. I'd probably represent the Cell itself as another stack view. Not sure exactly what the views look like and how they change, but it may end up as simple as hiding / unhiding the second view from the Stack View that represent a "cell".

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I ended up setting up a scroll view and I load 3 versions of my "cell" from nib and add as subviews. It seems to be working fine.

Comment: Got it! A stack view would pretty much do the same, but in addition - it may help to easier maintain UI instead of dealing with auto-layout constraints.